# error in argument supplied for foreach php

Tags: php, json

I have this code that show on Chrome browser one error.

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("file.json");
    $data =  json_decode($json, TRUE);


?>
<html>
<?php include 'cab.php'; ?>
<body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>

    <div class="container">
        <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tbl">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Data de publicação</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Empresa Contratada</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Empresa que Contratou</strong></td>
                <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Objecto adquirido</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Preço Contratual</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Data do Contrato</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($data as $item) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'publicationDate'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'contracted'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'contracting'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'id'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'objectBriefDescription'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'initialContractualPrice'}; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $item->{'signingDate'}; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php include 'rodape.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

the error that show on chrome is:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\base2\index.php on line 27
```

Someone can help me to solve that?

this file reeds a json file and show all information in a html table.

Comment: `foreach` expects the argument to be either an array or an object. `$data` isn't neither. So check the return value of `json_decode()`. If it is `NULL`, then check the return value of `file_get_contents()`. If it's `FALSE`, then check if the URL exists and so on... Moral: **Never assume success**.

Comment: do a var_dump($data); after you json_decode it and monitor the result .. is it really working

Comment: can you add output of `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: Note: simple object properties don't require `{}`. These should be simplified to `$item->publicationDate $item->contracted` etc...  The `{}` enclosed strings should only be used for dynamically constructed property names, which you don't have.

Comment: I think Amal Muarali's comment could be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
<table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Data de publicação</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Empresa Contratada</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Empresa que Contratou</strong></td>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Objecto adquirido</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Preço Contratual</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Data do Contrato</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      $json = file_get_contents("file.json");
      $data =  json_decode($json);
      if(count((array)$data)>0):
      foreach ($data as $item) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item->publicationDate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->contracted; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->contracting; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->objectBriefDescription; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->initialContractualPrice; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item->signingDate; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; else: echo "No data found"; endif; ?>
```